# Query to display output horizontally

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I need to display a query output in a horizontal manner. I have some example data

```
create table TestTable (id number, name varchar2(10))

insert into TestTable values (1, 'John')
insert into TestTable values (2, 'Mckensy')
insert into TestTable values (3, 'Valneech')
insert into TestTable values (4, 'Zeebra')

commit

select * from TestTable
```

This gets the output in a vertical view.

```
ID Name
==========
1  John
2  Mckensy
3  Valneech
4  Zeebra
```

However, I need to display it horizontally.

```
ID   1    2       3        4
Name John Mckensy Valneech Zeebra
```

How can one do this?

Comment: this is more of a display format issue, why would you like the data to come out of the DB like that, surely it would be easier to do this in the front end via some reporting service.

Comment: Hi Warrior, Thanks. for my requirement backend data is very less. we are not using any report tool. If i get the data through query, my job is completed 100% . So I am in need of that query. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To pivot, you should use the [pivot clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#CHDFAFIE) of the select statement:

```
select *
  from testtable
 pivot ( max(name)
         for id in (1,2,3,4)
       )
```

This is not particularly pretty to do in SQL, so you should consider carefully whether this is what you want to do. I normally use [Oracle Base](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php) for pivoting examples but there are many out there.

Here's a little [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/de90e/2) to demonstrate.

Comment: The SQL Fiddle link no longer works, though there's no reason for anyone to be surprised based on when this answer was posted. Could you update it?

Comment: [SQL Fiddle generally no longer works](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321437/458741) @AWright, it's not specific to this answer. I can't get the thing to load, but rereading this answer it'll be some sample data and a simple pivot statement. More of a "try it yourself" than any new information. The OP has already provided the DDL and DML for a small example, so it should be simple to run it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will help you:

```
select 'id', LISTAGG(id, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name)      
from testtable
union 
select 'name', LISTAGG(name, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name)
from testtable
```

EDIT:

or with pivot:

```
create table TestTable2 (id varchar2(30), name varchar2(10));

insert into TestTable2 values ('id', 'name');


insert into TestTable2
select cast(id as varchar2(30)) as id , name
from testtable

  select *
    from testtable2
    pivot (  max(name)
             for id in ('id',1,2,3,4) 
)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Your reply is very close to my requirement. But output should be in the columns. not just space between columns. Little more  help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[PIVOT](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php) operator is what you are looking for.