# Bash: Display CSV vertically

Tags: shell, csv

I am trying to display some CSV file by switching rows and columns, so that this:

```
a,b,name
20,10,"Hello World"
```

Would looks like:

```
a,20
b,10
name,"Hello World"
```

For instance in Sqlite one can use the [pivot clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328849/query-to-display-output-horizontally), but I'm looking for something more general and not SQL specific.

So is there an easy way to convert rows to columns by splitting them at a given separator (here `,`)?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but very close: [Transpose a file in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1729824/3266847)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
#########################################
# Matrix transpose with Awk
#
# Usage: matrixT file fs ofs
# The last two arguments are optional
#
# Kent
# 2011-07-07
#
#########################################
fs=${2:-" "}
ofs=${3:-" "}
file=$1

awk  -v FS="$fs" -v OFS="$ofs" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i,NR]=$i; }END{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        for(j=1;j<=NR;j++)
            printf "%s%s", a[i,j], (j==NR? ORS:OFS);
    } 
}' "$file"
```

Sometimes I need do this also quite often, so I wrote a script (see above).

You can do :

```
theScript.sh file ","  ","
```